# Excel Formula - Criteria To Concatenate multiple cells by matching source cell

Tags: excel

I am Looking to concatenates multiple cells into one by Index-matching the criteria

The below formula is not pulling in all the required UPCs against the specified criteria

```
 =INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($D:$D,$A:$A,0))
```

I would like the end result to look like COL E2 in the below image with semi-colons in between every value `;`

[image]

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have <kbd>Office365</kbd> then use `TEXTJOIN()` with `FILTER()` function.

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B$15,$A$2:$A$15=D2))
```

> Edit: Assuming you don't have access to `O365` dynamic formulas. Then try below array formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$15=D2,$B$2:$B$15,""))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: appreciate the swift response. I am using Office 365. Upon trying both solutions, excel throws an error "That function isn't Valid"

Comment: Can you please check you have `FILTER()` function to your excel?

Comment: No, I do not. I only have the FILTERXML() function

Comment: @fahadmanzur Can you please try my edited answer.

Comment: Yes it worked. You are life saver. Thank you so much good sir.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using the `CONCAT` function:

```
=CONCAT(FILTER(B:B, A:A=D2)&";")
```

**Explanation:**

1. The `FILTER` logic is just like Harun24HR suggested. Creating an array of all the values in B where the value in A is equal to D2.
2. The & operator works on each element in the array and adds a delimiter ";" to each value.
3. Finally, the `CONCAT` function combines all of the elements in the array into a single string.

Comment: It will add an extra semicolon `;` to end of the every result.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, excel throws an error. =FILTERXML is the only option being displayed

Comment: @harun24HR Yes, you are right, there will be an extra ";" at the end of each line. I assumed that is fine.

Comment: But more puzzling is the issue with the `FILTER` function. Apparently, it is still not available in all subscriptions. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Thank you Dave, that worked great for me where the others didn't.